# Show posts from specific category - Wordpress array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this array on my template options:

```
$args = array(

                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array('post-format-quote', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-audio'),
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        'category_name' => 'noticias'

                    )
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'MEDICAL_META_embed_code',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'MEDICAL_META_gallery',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    )
                )
            );
```

If you see the line `'category_name' => 'noticias'`, noticias is the category I want to show on home page, but that line isn't working, maybe 'category_name' isn't the best choice here...

I've read on wordpress documentation, but there's no array example, just functions, Is there a way to accomplish this on an array like this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the category ID if you know exactly which category you need to display.

Comment: Hi, yes, but I can't find a function for this, I mean, of course there are, but I just need it on the array, like: 'category_id' => 'number'?'

Comment: Did you try to put cat => '23' (put noticias cat ID here) one level above where it is now (like below the sticky post param). ??

Comment: Ya, tried now with 'cat', in this place, and it works now... AWESOME!  lol, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of those who read this thread, you can filter specific categories in the query args array using the following parameters

```
cat (int) - use category id.
category_name (string) - use category slug (NOT name).
category__and (array) - use category id.
category__in (array) - use category id.
category__not_in (array) - use category id.
```

The OP's issue can be solved by simply modifying the array as shown here

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'cat' => '777' // Put the cat ID here
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                     ... 
                     ...
                     )
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

For display post of specific category u can use `WP Query` function,for this function refer [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)